# Wifi issues with multiple devices

Tags: network, wifi, internet, router

I have about 4 devices always using the internet on my home wifi network. Everything is fine and dandy until I start to do intensive bandwidth stuff like gaming and streaming movies. So I thought this was an issue with my internet speed so I upgraded to 100mbps down and 20mbps up but this hasn't improved the issue.

I have a 3 year old Linksys E4200 router. I've tried different DNS servers and i've looked for the optimal wifi frequency so that there's no interference with neighboring wifi. Because of the distance of my devices I cannot connect anything to ethernet.

Please help. My hulu keeps glitching and I can't use my laptop and xbox at the same time with out something slowing down.

One other thing is I have my xbox on DMZ would this cause any issues?

Thank you in advance for you time and help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a network question. Nothing to do with Apple anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related to Apple products or their use.

Answer (score 1):

The 100/24 Mbps are actually good numbers.

The question is are those actually arriving at your computer.

One suggestion I would make is for you to switch to 5GHz router/Network.

That should eliminate lots of neighborhood interference.

5GHz also has much higher data transfer rate between your router and your computer.

On Mac the Transfer Rate is shown in the WiFi profile and it is the one key measure how fast is your connection to the router.

My Transmit Rates are 70 on a 2.4 GHz network and 250 on my 5 GHz network.

PS, try turning off the dual frequency on your Router.

Comment: I have tried both dual and single frequencies. When I have my mac on 5ghz the speed goes from 30mbps on 2.4ghz to 5mbps on 5ghz. When I have single frequency on it's at 30mbps but only when none of my other devices are connected. And considering I have 100mbps down shouldn't there be 70mbps left for the other devices to use?

Comment: hmm. something is upside down (it should be way faster on 5GHz), so where do you get/read the mbps ? Please look at the Transmit rate numbers.

Comment: I use speedtest.net then I use cox internet speed test tool on their website. Both get the same numbers. 30mbps with 2.4ghz and 5mbps with 5ghz. I know it's strange. I've restarted the router, did a factory reset, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Never game/stream on Wireless. Run Ethernet cable. Wireless bandwidth drops tremendously when another connection is streaming or gaming. It has to do with the way routers split or share bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Wi-Fi channel in your router's configuration options. Often times one's neighborhood is full of residents all using the same channel, which results in loads of interference.

[Find Best Wi-Fi Channel](http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/11/find-best-wi-fi-channel-wireless-tool-mac/)

Answer (score -2):

I think the 30mbps is correctly enough via wifi for your 100mbps bandwidth that's from your ISP to your router which is wired connection not the wifi connection;

My iMac used 2.4ghz because 2.4ghz more stable than 5ghz in a serious environment, and I got the simlar result: 32+-2mbps from www.speedtest.net; 
Googled Linksys E4200, it marked 750M，2.4Ghz 300Mbps，5Ghz 450Mbps, 
so check your wifi environment: distance, walls, and use wired connection as possible.